# When I deploy openedx on Ubuntu, why does Bootstrap the Ansible installation command fail?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, openedx

This is the command that needs to be executed：
Bootstrap the Ansible installation:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/configuration/$OPENEDX_RELEASE/util/install/ansible-bootstrap.sh -O - | sudo -E bash
```

Here are the installation instructions I refer to：
[text](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/1969455764/Koa+Native+Open+edX+platform+Ubuntu+20.04+64+bit+Installation)

This is an error when I run this command：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oG4U.png)